# Server 2012 with DAC setup

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to setup DAC in Server 2012 Standard. However, it gets a little confusing on how the client has groups. 8 total groups (including Administrators and All Users). However, 1 user might be a member of 3 different groups, another member might be a member of 2 of those 3 & member of 2 more. Only a few users out of 28 are in the same groups. So, setting up by primary groups doesn't seem to be a best practice.

So, looking for suggestions on setting up DAC for user access when the groups are not the best. Anyone have any ideas, links, examples, or etc. that can be shared to assist?

Thanks in advance,
Gene

Answer (score 1):

DAC uses claims to create access policies.  Groups are only 1 of the claimtypes you could use.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846167.aspx for an example using department.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Understood. I was hoping for some guidance when it comes to setting up DAC when groups isn't possible. If another user has had experience with a different claim. I have seen that example with departments, and read it many times. However, it does not fit into my scenario, and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: what claims would you like to use?  Why are the groups not possible?

Comment: Because users are members of different groups, and not all users are in the same groups to be consistent. Unless I am misunderstanding. User 1 might be in HR, IT, and All, User 2 is in HR, All, Manager, and Internal. User 3 is in HR, IT, Internal, and Remote.

Comment: what users are in what groups is just a claim.  whatever claimset you use is what has to be in common, you don't need to create or have a group- just a claim value, groups are just really convenient since they are easily created and populated.  if you want completely arbitray groupings then you must use a group (even without DAC)